# Join two process by pid in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I created two process by using fork in python as

```
import os
import sys
pid = os.fork()
if pid > 0:
   # set some variable ( Lets say SETTING_A )
   # Lets execute
   os.waitpid(pid,0)
else:
   pid = os.fork()
   if pid > 0:
      # Set some other variable ( Lets say SETTING_B )
      # Let Execute
      os.waitpid(pid, 0)
   else:
      sys.exit(0)
# COMMON WORKFLOW
```

**Problem:**

Lets assume my script run with `SETTING_A` takes `10 sec`. while same script run with `SETTING_B` takes `2 min`. I want to run two instances of my script with two different setting in parallel. To make sure parent process wait for child to finish, I used `os.waitpid()`, but It made it sequential execution. It run first with setting `B` and then `A`. How can I maintain parallelism and also my parent process wait until child process finish. I tried searching `join()` but this is with `Process()` class in python. Is there any way I can join these process by pid without affecting too much change.

Comment: Why don't you use the `multiprocessing` module instead? It does all that dirty work for you (and as a bonus is cross-platform).

Comment: You should switch to the multiprocessing module.

Comment: there is a problem, when I am using p = Process(target=Fun, arg=(data)) and data is object of class Data having lots of field. it complaining .... .TypeError: 'Data' object is not iterable

Comment: Try arg=(data,) to make it iterable.